# windows server 2008 dns server, set dns for specific ip

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

I am trying to do one thing, but fail to do so: create specific dns entry for only one FQDN.
This is my scenario: I have domain xxyy.lan and dns for it.
I have xxyy.com on the internet, and it has it own dns server.

But now, I would like to all users in the domain to resolve 1 address like data.xxyy.com to point to my local ip 192.168.x.x. The data.xxyy.com exist on the internet and it has public ip, but I would like it to got directly to my local server.

I know I can set it up on local machines with hosts file, but I would like to set it globally on my AD controller.

Thank you
Dorijan

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to get your local dns server to provide the local IP address when queried for your public name.

1. Go into DNS -> right click Forward Lookup Zones -> New Zone -> Primary Zone -> default replication are fine -> for Zone Name: enter the FQDN -> Do not allow dynamic updates -> finish.
2. Go into the zone you just created and make an A record.  Leave the name field blank and specify the IP address you want to go along with your FQDN.